# Laravel CORS Problem on the first post, how to solve it?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, cors

can anyone help me please?
So, I work in React as the frontend and Laravel as the backend. I have a feature about uploading files. When I click upload button for the first time. It will get me a CORS Error, I check the network tab and there is no CORS response header. But when I click it again (without changing anything), it can be done and there are CORS configuration.

I have used my own CORS configuration and /fruitcake/laravel-cors. It still gets me the same problem.

[First Time Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6KvX.png)

[Second Time Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjSe5.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you disable CSRF protection for the routes with CORS configuration?

Are you sure both requests are on the same route? The ratelimiter headers are also missing in the first response.